# Configure SSL in Apache with Tomcat 7 and Spring MVC webapp

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, tomcat7

My situation is the following:

1. I have an Apache Server in front of a Tomcat that serves plain HTML.
2. I want to configure SSL in Apache and keeps Tomcat serving plain HTML.
3. I want keep working both protocols, HTTP and HTTPS.
4. My actual configuration is like this:

I enable a new virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
          SSLEngine on
          SSLCertificateFile      /etc/apache2/conf/ssl/mydomain.crt
          SSLCertificateKeyFile  /etc/apache2/conf/ssl/mydomain.key
          SSLCertificateChainFile   /etc/apache2/conf/ssl/intermediate_mydomain_ca.crt
          ProxyRequests Off
          ProxyPreserveHost On
          ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/app
          ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/app
    </VirtualHost>
```

I'm also enable an AJP Connector on Tomcat's port 8009

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8080" />
```

5. Now, I have this situation:

   - https://example.com--> https://example.com/app (Apache to Tomcat
     is working OK).

The problem is that Spring returns a HTTP redirect instead HTTPS.

How can I keep these redirects into the HTTPS protocol?

Thanks in advance

Comment: mod_proxy_ajp should automatically forward the TLS info to Tomcat. That should mean that the protocol information is available to Tomcat. How is the redirect constructed?

Comment: Finally I solve it. First, in the Virtual Host you have to add that:  `RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"`. Then, in server.xml file configure a Valve like this: `<Valve
  className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve"
  internalProxies=".*"
  protocolHeader="X-Forwarded-Proto"
  httpsServerPort="443"/>`